# How to output the name of their foreign key id

Tags: php

I have a problem, I want that each id in the foreign key can output the name instead of their  id. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9QvZ.png) is the image.

Here's my code :

```
<table class="altrowstable" data-responsive="table" >
                <thead >
                    <tr>
                        <th> IDno</th>
                        <th> Lastname </th>
                        <th> Firstname </th>
                        <th> Department </th>
                        <th> Program </th>
                        <th> Action</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody> 
                 <div style="text-align:center; line-height:50px;"> 
                        <?php
                        include('../connection/connect.php');
                        $YearNow=Date('Y');

                        $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM student,school_year  where  user_type =3 AND student.syearid = school_year.syearid AND school_year.from_year like $YearNow ");
                        $result->execute();
                        for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
                        ?>
                    <tr class="record">
                        <td><?php echo $row['idno']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?></td>
//name belong's to their id's
                            <td><?php echo $row['dept_id']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['progid']; ?></td>

                    <td><a style="border:1px solid grey; background:grey; border-radius:10%; padding:7px 12px; color:white; text-decoration:none; " href="addcandidates.php?idno=<?php echo $row['idno']; ?>" > Running</a></div></td>
</tr>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
            </tbody>
                </table>
```

Thanks guys need a help

Comment: you use any framework ?

Comment: and please tell table name in your image

Comment: no I didn't use any framework

Comment: I've just update my image, I was mistake for the first image. Student table the foreign key is the progid

Comment: check my answer on the update you need to do to your query. But you should try a bit more before posting questions. Evaluate the code you already have. You were not far away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace this line

```
<td><?php echo $row['progid']; ?></td>
```

by this one

```
<td><?php echo $row['prog_name']; ?></td>
```

To use the field you want

You also need to adapt your query to select program infos if not already in the table school_year or student (with a join) :

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM student
    INNER JOIN school_year ON student.syearid = school_year.syearid
    INNER JOIN program ON student.progid = program.progid
    WHERE user_type =3
    AND school_year.from_year like $YearNow ");
```

Assuming the program table is called "program"

Comment: SQL injection vulnerability !

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<td><?php echo $row['progid']; ?></td>
```

to

```
<td><?php echo $row['prog_name']; ?></td>
```

And I would recommend to study both php and sql

Answer (score 0):

Change

`<td><?php echo $row['progid']; ?></td>`

by

`<td><?php echo $row['prog_name']; ?></td>`

Answer (score 0):

inside the loop:

```
for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
$program = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM program where  progid = :progid");
$program->execute(array('progid' => $row['progid']));
$p = $program->fetch();
```

now you can use it as follow: `$p['prog_name']`